# SQL server firewall rules

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I want to allow all IP's to access the SQL server.

```
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "fw" {
  name                = "${var.db_name}-fwrules"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.server.name
  start_ip_address    = var.start_ip_address
  end_ip_address      = var.end_ip_address
}
```

I have set the start_ip and end_ip to 0.0.0.0 but when I check in the Azure portal it says no firewall rule added but when I put my own IP as start_ip and end_ip, it applies the rule. How do I add all Ip's to the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow all IP addresses through Firewall, then your `start_ip_address` should be `0.0.0.0` and your `end_ip_address` should be `255.255.255.255`.

When you set both `start_ip_address` and `end_ip_address` to `0.0.0.0`, Firewall only allows Azure services to access your database.